# Math.max() работает неисправно

Tags: javascript

не выводит максимальное число, почему?

```
x = [-7,37,4,12,2,5,7]
    
    
let h = 0
for(i=0;i<x.length;i++){
    h = Math.max(x[i])
}
console.log(h)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Не выводит, потому что `Math.max` принимает два или больше аргументов. Попробуйте сделать так:

```
let x = [-7,37,4,12,2,5,7]
    
    
let h = 0

h = Math.max.apply (null, x);

console.log(h);
```

Comment: Почитал доку, оказывается Math.max работает и с 0 и с 1 аргументами тоже - *"function returns the largest of the zero or more numbers given as input"*.

Comment: @Kromster в случае с одним аргументом функция возвращает его же, а с нулем - infinity. ))

Comment: Так, а для чего собственно цикл? `let h = Math.max.apply(null, x);` сделает то же самое. А в цикле один и тот же результат просто повторяется)

Comment: Можно ещё `let h = Math.max(...x);`.

Answer (score 2):

```js
x = [-7,37,4,12,2,5,7]
console.log(Math.max(...x))
```

Answer (score 1):

Функция `Math.max` совершенно исправна. Просто надо читать документацию и смотреть как ей пользоваться.

Функция `Math.max` взвращает максимальное из переданных в нее чисел. Естественно, если вы каждый раз передаете только одно число - оно максимально.

Передавать надо два числа:

```
h = Math.max(h, x[i])
```